# Read input file block by block in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to read a text file from input and read it block by block. I don't want to read the input file line by line and I don't want to use AWK, because the blocks should be in while or for. How can i read text file, block by block with while or for loop? this is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v RS='Uri' '{ print $0 }' parse_xml
while read -r i # problem is here, read command can't read block input
do
    Uri=$(awk '{print $3}' $i) 
    Status=$(echo $i | awk '/Status/{print $3 }' )
    Country=$(echo $i | awk '/Country/{print $3 }')
    IP=$(echo $i | awk '/IP/ {print $3}')
    HTTPServer=$(echo $i | awk '/HTTPServer/ {print $3}')
    Title=$(echo $i | awk '/Title/ {print $3}')
    PoweredBy=$(echo $i | awk '/X-Powered-By/ {print $3}')
    ASP_NET=$(awk '/ASP_NET/ {print $3}' $i)
    JQuery=$(awk '/JQuery/ {print $3}' $i)
    Microsoft_IIS=$(awk '/Microsoft-IIS/ {print $3}' $i)
    Apache=$(awk '/Apache/ {print $3}' $i)
    echo "$Uri -- $Status -- $Country -- $IP -- $STTPServer -- $Title -- $PoweredBy -- $ASP_NET -- $JQuery -- $Microsoft_IIS -- $Apache "
done < pars_xml
```

and this is my input file:

```
: http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx     
Status : 200     
nginx : 1.2.1     
Country : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  
Title : Welcome to nginx!   
IP : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx     
HTTPServer : nginx/1.2.1



: http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    
Status : 200     
X-Powered-By : ASP.NET     
HttpOnly : ASP.NET_SessionId     
HTML5 :      
ASP_NET : 4.0.30319     
Country : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  
Title : .:%D9%BE%D8%A7%DB%8C%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%87 %D8%A7%D8%B7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B9 %D8%B1%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%86%DB%8C %D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%86:.  
Script : text/javascript     
Cookies : ASP.NET_PrivateSessionID ASP.NET_SessionId    
IP : xxxxxxxxxxxxxx     
JQuery : 1.4.2     
HTTPServer : Microsoft-IIS/7.5     
Microsoft-IIS : 7.5     

: http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx     
Status : 200     
Meta-Refresh-Redirect : /Intranet     
X-Powered-By : ASP.NET     
ASP_NET :      
Country : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  
IP : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx     
HTTPServer : Microsoft-IIS/7.0     
Microsoft-IIS : 7.0     

: http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    
Status : 301     
X-Powered-By : ASP.NET     
ASP_NET :      
Country : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  
Title : Document Moved    
IP : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    
HTTPServer : Microsoft-IIS/7.0     
Microsoft-IIS : 7.0     
RedirectLocation : http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: If you're already using `awk` to extract columns, why not use it to separate the blocks (`records` in awk) too?

Comment: I've already explained my reason. I want to read input via while or for loop (Just this way). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This doesn't explain the reason. You're not doing anything inside your loop which cannot be done in awk directly.

Comment: You do realise awk has while and for loops ?

Comment: Awk is an useful tool, but it can't be used in this case. I can't use so many conditions together in Awk.

Comment: You can use as many conditions as you want in awk

Comment: I've got it.Thank you. I will work on it.

Comment: What do you mean by "block", anyway?  Many of us will interpret it to mean the allocation unit of your file system (512-byte blocks is common) whereas it seems from the text of your question that you actually want to read records -- which incidentally Awk is very good at.

Comment: OK, I've searched about AWK last day, but I haven't reach anything appropriate to my situation. Could any tell me how I can use AWK for my code to read input? How to write it with AWK?

Comment: I've done it without awk! exactly as what it was in my mind!